# Need to resolve an issue with unity editor using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to resolve an issue. When I am rotating the camera, how do I change the camera movement in the Input.getaxis to my middle mouse click instead of the standard Horizontal and Vertical with my arrow key pad.

```
void Update()
{
    yaw += speedH * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    pitch -= speedV * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you use a more descriptive question title?

Comment: Not sure how I could use a more descriptive title without making it to long, it's a very simple and narrow question. Thought the title encapsulated the simple question well? If not I'm open to recommendations on the title.

Comment: Well the title `Need to resolve an issue with unity editor using c#` is describing each and every question here on StackOverflow related to Unity and c# .... your question is specially about defining what `GetAxis` shall refer to -> [Input Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get mouse wheel data by calling:

`Input.mouseScrollDelta.y`

If this value is positive you are scrolling up and if its negative you are scrolling down.

If you need to check if the middle mouse button is pressed you can call `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2)`

Take a look at [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mouseScrollDelta.html) documentation for more information